# Auto increment a table column using python

Tags: python, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, auto-increment

In `Hive` I have a table called test. In this table I want to have 5 columns.

```
ID, start_time, end_time, min_value, max_value.
```

Now using `Pyspark` I want to populate this table.

I am doing like below in my python file:

```
start_time='4/5/2017'
end_time='5/4/2017'
min_value='1'
max_value='100'

sqlContext.sql("insert into table testing.test select '{}','{}','{}','{}','{}'".format(id,start_time,end_time,min_value,max_value))
```

In this above script start_time, end_time, min_value, max_value I will get these values as part of the script.

Now what I want is the column should be `Auto incremented` when ever there is an insert statement is being executed then there should be 
`id` value added to it.

Is it possible to that using python? if yes then

How can I do auto increment for column `ID` in my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply make an ID variable, and add to it, whenever you also execute the insert command, something like:

```
id = 1 #outside of the loop or function, possibly make it a global variable

#some loop or function#

sqlContext.sql(....)

id = id + 1
```

if you are going to be populating that database more often than once (which is likely) you should obtain the id variable from the latest/highest value of the database, so it doesnt repeat ; )